# Mean of two rasterstacks while maintaining layer structure

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

Currently I am in the works combining two rasterstacks both containing a different projection of the same data into one rasterstack by taking the mean of the two layers at the same position in the stacks. Problem is that applying the mean to both datasets takes the mean of the entire stacks, removing the layer structure and producing two rasters:

```
stack1 = raster_list[[1]]
stack2 = raster_list[[2]]
sapply(c(stack1, stack2) FUN = mean)
[[1]]
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 196, 205, 40180  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.08333588, 0.08333359  (x, y)
extent      : 64.24827, 81.33213, 19.99832, 36.33171  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : -14.92228, 97.07268  (min, max)


[[2]]
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 196, 205, 40180  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.08333588, 0.08333359  (x, y)
extent      : 64.24827, 81.33213, 19.99832, 36.33171  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : -19.61176, 151.9439  (min, max)
```

How could I best proceed with this, preferable avoiding a for loop that seperates them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible example with data:

```
library(raster)
s1 <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
s2 <- sqrt(s1)
```

What you do not want, as it creates a single RasterLayer:

```
m1 <- mean(s1, s2)
nlayers(m1)
# [1] 1
```

Instead, to do the layer-by-layer mean:

```
m2 <- (s1 + s2) / 2
nlayers(m2)
# [1] 3
```

or:

```
m3 <- overlay(s1, s2, fun=mean)
```

If you have `NA`s that you want to ignore:

```
m4 <- overlay(s1, s2, fun=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```